# Ftp Upload a folder from sdcard to ftp Android

Tags: android, apache, upload, ftp

Hi all any java geek can help me? I need to upload a folder with subs folders to my ftp.
I found some sample code,but only for a singel file.
And i dont know how to change it to upload a folder.I used google but no anwser found.

```
        String server = "192.168.1.2";
    String username = "test";
    String password = "test";
    String local = "mnt/sdcard/shopinglist/"; #This path i need to upload

    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
  try
  {
      System.out.println( "Connecting" );
      ftp.connect(server);
      if(!ftp.login(username, password))
      {
          System.out.println( "Login failed" );
          ftp.logout();
          return;
      }
      int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
      System.out.println( "Connect returned: " + reply );
      if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
          ftp.disconnect();
          System.out.println( "Connection failed" );
          return;
      }
      ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(local);
      ftp.setFileType(ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
      System.out.println( "Uploading File" );
      boolean store = ftp.storeFile("mnt/sdcard/shopinglist/",in); # ??? Any help ???
      in.close();
      ftp.logout();
      ftp.disconnect();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

Thanks to all.

Comment: push ... anybody can please help

Comment: 2 day no news -.- ° its is realy so hard to do this ? Im very new in android java dev but we need only list the items on the folder and upload it file for file.Any idee geeks dev ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below if it helps

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    // FTP URL (Starts with ftp://, sftp:// or ftps:// followed by hostname and port).
    Uri ftpUri = Uri.parse("ftp://yourftpserver.com");
    intent.setDataAndType(ftpUri, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/lysesoft.andftp.uri");
    // FTP credentials (optional)
    intent.putExtra("ftp_username", "anonymous");
    intent.putExtra("ftp_password", "something@somewhere.com");
    //intent.putExtra("ftp_keyfile", "/sdcard/dsakey.txt");
    //intent.putExtra("ftp_keypass", "optionalkeypassword");
    // FTP settings (optional)
    intent.putExtra("ftp_pasv", "true");
    //intent.putExtra("ftp_resume", "true");
    //intent.putExtra("ftp_encoding", "UTF8");
    // Upload
    intent.putExtra("command_type", "upload");
    // Activity title
    intent.putExtra("progress_title", "Uploading folder ...");
    intent.putExtra("local_file1", "/sdcard/localfolder");
    // Optional initial remote folder (it must exist before upload)
    intent.putExtra("remote_folder", "remotefolder/uploadedfolder");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Let me Know if it helps